# Confused about Nested loops Big-O runtime when j=i

Tags: big-o

Confused about what the big-Oh of the following code would be:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    for(int j=i;j<array.length();j++){}
}
```

Is it O(n^2)? The part that confuses me is j=i and how that will effect runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is O((array.length)^2).

- The two loops result in 1/2*n*(n+1) calls of the inner block
- This is equivalent to 1/2*n*n + 1/2*n*1.
- Since constant factors are irrelevant in the O(n) notation, your code is exactly O((array.length)^2).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *array.length* is *n* the total execution of inner loop is:

```
round 1 (i=0) : n           this round j = 0 to n-1
round 2 (i=1) : n-1         this round j = 1 to n-1
   .
   .
   . 
round n (i=n-1) : 1         this round j = n-1 to n-1
--------------------------------
 Total :  n*(n+1)/2 is in O(n^2)
```

> 1+ 2+ ... + n = n(n+1) / 2
>    [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)